# What python based ajax push servers are good to work with

Tags: python, real-time, comet, ajax-push

I have a web application im currently working on in python. I'm using Django as my web framework currently. I intend to integrate real-time web features into the application using ajax push. However, I'm a bit confused as to what python based push server i should adopt. I've heard of a few of them, Orbited, Gevent, Tornado, but my main issue right now is that i'm a green horn when it comes to realtime web applications. I'd like to use python and i'd like a framework with good documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of people choose [gevent](http://gevent.org) for webapps with real-time features because of the speed, ease of use and a number of supporting packages.

Take a look at these packages:

- [gevent-socketio](https://bitbucket.org/Jeffrey/gevent-socketio)
- [django-socketio](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-socketio/)

and these tutorials:

- [Evented Django part one: Socket.IO and gevent](http://codysoyland.com/2011/feb/6/evented-django-part-one-socketio-and-gevent/)
- [New and hot, part 4: Pyramid, Socket.IO and Gevent](http://blog.abourget.net/2011/3/17/new-and-hot-part-4-pyramid-socket-io-gevent/)
- [Real-time Web Apps with Django and WebSockets](http://blog.jupo.org/post/8858247674/real-time-web-apps-with-django-and-websockets)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

APE seems a cool thing.

I think it's not a problem to make it work with PDjango as a backend.

Comment: I'll check it out. I hope the documentation is good enough though. Thanks all the same

Answer (score 0):

I think the most popular is tornado open-sourced by facebook. It also has pretty decent documentation.